# Bash. cat file interpret text as usual, but cat -t text find some symvals (^A) etc

Tags: bash, ascii, cat

What is that symbol meaning?
cat text.txt

```
str          !

()
   ()  
()
         end.
```

cat -t text.txt

```
str          !

(^A)
   (^B)  
(^F)
^I end.
```

what that symbol meaning? Why does it view with flag t?

Comment: `Why does it view with flag t?` I do not know what answer do you expect to get. Because `cat` was programmed that way to do it when you pass flag `t`? What do you mean exactly by "why"?

Comment: I thought -t remove tabulation into ^I only. Now I see it shows hidden symbols. TY

Comment: See `cat --help` or `man cat` for documentation.

Comment: See: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=cat+-t+text.txt and https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=cat+-vT+text.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what that symbol meaning?

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation :

> Caret notation is a notation for control characters in ASCII. The notation assigns ^A to control-code 1, sequentially through the alphabet to ^Z assigned to control-code 26 (0x1A). For the control-codes outside of the range 1–26, the notation extends to the adjacent, non-alphabetic ASCII characters.

`^A` means byte 0x01, `^B` means byte 0x02, etc.

Comment: TY. That what I wanted to see.